# mysql order by with duplicates, optional parameter?

Tags: mysql

For example the values for all rows for column `rating` are zero. `ORDER BY rating DESC` would be primary, Is there a way to do a secondary `ORDER BY`.

If `ORDER BY rating DESC` has duplicates, then do `ORDER BY name DESC`?  Is this possible?

---

```
 id   | name  | rating
  1   | one   |  0
  2   | two   |  0
  3   | three |  0
  4   | four  |  0
  5   | five  |  0
  6   | six   |  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.

Just add the second column in `order by` clause

```
ORDER BY rating DESC, name DESC
```